# How to make hidden filed dynamically using xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML as out and based on that i want to creat input hidden filed dynamically. Suppose i have below xml as output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MB>
    <RQ>
        <fldDeviceId><![CDATA[Iyh4KnNEU6GDcl4qCQMBzil2wOI=]]></fldDeviceId>
        <uid><![CDATA[fdsfs]]></uid>
        <Account><![CDATA[fsdfds]]></Account>
        <OperatorType><![CDATA[M]]></OperatorType>
        <Mobile><![CDATA[9029938117]]></Mobile>
        <User-Agent><![CDATA[WindowsPhone]]></User-Agent>
        <sessionKey><![CDATA[83727d34-bfef-45ca-955b-4695d035cd98]]></sessionKey>
        <Account_txt><![CDATA[fsafsa- Chandivali, Mumbai]]></Account_txt>
        <Amount><![CDATA[10]]></Amount>
        <requestType><![CDATA[ICPMR]]></requestType>
        <OperationId><![CDATA[dfs]]></OperationId>
        <Operator_txt><![CDATA[AIRCEL]]></Operator_txt>
        <fldLangId><![CDATA[en-US]]></fldLangId>
        <Operator><![CDATA[ARC]]></Operator>
        <TransSeq><![CDATA[03]]></TransSeq>
    </RQ>
    <RS>
        <CardNo>#5435345</CardNo>
        <AuthChar1>B</AuthChar1>
        <AuthChar2>H</AuthChar2>
        <AuthChar3>O</AuthChar3>
    </RS>
</MB>
```

In  there may be thousand of tags , all i want in input hidden filed like given below in xslt transformation.

```
<input type="hidden" id="{fldDeviceId}" value="fldDeviceId" />
<input type="hidden" id="{uid}" value="uid" />
```

and so on...i don't want to write thousand of line. How to do that just help me out.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear exactly what records in the XML you want "hidden", but assuming it is just one ones under **RQ**, you could define a template like so

```
<xsl:template match="RQ/*">
    <input type="hidden" id="{.}" value="{local-name()}" />
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT for example

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="RQ/*" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="RQ/*">
        <input type="hidden" id="{.}" value="{local-name()}" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```